# About dependency of random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, independence

*I am always considering non-discrete/non-finite probability spaces $\Omega$. For everything that follows feel free to assume $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$.*

Say you have 2 random variables $X_1,X_2 :\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Now an event based definition of $X_1$ and $X_2$ being ``independent" is as follows : "$X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables if for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\mathbb{P}((X_1 \leq x)\cap(X_2 \leq y)) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x)\mathbb{P}(X_2 \leq y)$" (Am I right?)

- Are there natural examples of pairs of independent random variables whose descriptions can be given as maps $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?
- Is the above setup enough to ensure that there exists a joint-distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$? If yes, how?
- When would one prefer to use a joint-distribution based definition of ``independence" as opposed to such an event based defition and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

On $(0,1)$ if you define $X_n(\omega)$ as the n-th coefficient in the expansion of $\omega$ to base $2$ then the random variables $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ are independent. The statement $P\{X\leq x,Y\leq y\}=P\{X\leq x\}P\{Y\leq y\}$ for all $x,y$ is equivalent to the statement $P(X\in A, Y \in B)=P(X\in A)P( Y \in B)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb R$. (I suppose this is what you mean by event based definition of independence).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! (1) I was looking for "natural" example of independent random variables which can be described as such $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Could you kindly provides some? Say some examples in terms of random variables with commonly used distributions like Gaussian, chi^2 etc.. (2) I agree that the definition I gave in the question is the event based definition. I wanted to know when can one give a joint distribution based definition and when is it more or less useful. (In my setup is a joint-distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ guaranteed to exist?)

Comment: On $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ the coordinate functions $(x,y) \to x$ and $(x,y) \to y$ are independent random variables.

Comment: Well, the $X_1$ and $X_2$ that you gave are not random variables with very "standard" distributions. Thats what makes them "unnatural" in my view. I am looking for situations which can be specified as maps and the distributions of the two random variables is something "nice" like Gaussian etc.

Comment: Both have uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Comment: hmm. Can one lets say give examples of $X_1$ and $X_2$ maps n this form such that the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is the 2-dimensional standard Gaussian?

Comment: Yes, take $F^{-1}(X_1),F^{-1}(X_2)$ where $F$ is a normal cdf.